# Alternate Color for Highlighting Table Rows or Columns

Tags: css, sapui5

The table alternative color as [suggested in the dev guide](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.34.0/#docs/guide/7ec7885ce75c4237aadc67d83f64b66e.html) doesn't work.

```
#salesarea tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
    background: rgb(245, 245, 245);
}
```

Even though I use the ID of the sap.m.Table, the CSS doesn't work!

Edited to add code:
I'm using xml/desktop version and the view is in shell.

### view.xml

```
<Table
    id="qcTable"
    inset="false"
>
    <columns>
        <Column
            hAlign="Center"
            popinDisplay="Inline"
            width="10%"
        >
            <header>
                <Label text="Col 1"/>
            </header>
        </Column>
        <Column
            hAlign="Center"
            popinDisplay = "Inline"
        >
            <header>
                <Label text="Col2"/>
            </header>
        </Column>
    </columns>
</Table>
```

### style.css

```
//using generated id during runtime

#viewCQ--qcTable-tblBody tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
    background: rgb(245, 245, 245) !important;
}

//using direct id of table

#viewCQ tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
    background: rgb(245, 245, 245) !important;
}

//using class of table

.viewCQ tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
    background: rgb(245, 245, 245) !important;
}
```

Comment: UI5 now supports alternate colors. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/46949646/5846045

Answer (score 1):

wow.. just found the mistake myself.. i'm supposed to use

**viewCQ--qcTable-listUl**

not

```
viewCQ--qcTable-tblBody.
```

anyways thanks to all who responded quickly. tnx again.

Comment: -1. Please, **do not rely on global IDs** as they're always dynamic. E.g. view IDs don't always start with the user-defined (e.g. `viewCQ`) or generated ID but often with component's ID which is also the case when the app is deployed on FLP even if there was no component ID set explicitly. It gets even worse when the app has nested components with `autoPrefixId` enabled, making the global ID very long with multiple and single hyphens in between. Instead, make use of the property that enables alternate row colors out-of-the-box as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/46949646/5846045

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using Css property for giving colors we can use sap.m.ObjectStatus

```
 var iDtemplate = new sap.m.ColumnListItem("idTemplate",{
             type: "Navigation",
              visible: true,
              selected: true,
                cells:[


                       new sap.m.ObjectStatus({
                           text:"{SlNo}",
                       }).bindProperty("state", "number", function(value) {
                              return getStatusColor(value);
                       }),


                      new sap.m.ObjectStatus({
                           text:"{Name}",
                       }).bindProperty("state", "number", function(value) {
                              return getStatusColor(value);
                       }),
                       ],
                     pressListMethod: function(event){
                            var bindingContext = event.getSource().getBindingContext();

                     }
            });

            function getStatusColor(status) {
                 if (status === '') {
                   return "Error";
                 } 

                 else {
                     return "Success";
                 }
                }
```

Based on the number field we are giving colors to columns Slno and Name.

Answer (score 0):

This approach does work. You need to ensure the CSS selectors are pointing to the right place. Here's an example (in a StackOverflow snippet):

```js
new sap.m.Table("salesarea", {
  columns : [
    new sap.m.Column({
      header : new sap.m.Text({text: "Place"})
    })
  ],
  items: {
    path: "/places",
    template: new sap.m.ColumnListItem({
      cells : [
        new sap.m.Text({text: "{name}"})
      ]
    })
  }
})
.setModel(new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel({
  places: [
    { name: "Manchester" },
    { name: "Liverpool" },
    { name: "Leeds" },
    { name: "Sheffield" }
  ]
}))
.placeAt("content");
```

```css
#salesarea tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
    background: rgb(245, 245, 245);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js" id="sap-ui-bootstrap" data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m" data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal"></script>
<div id="content"></div>
```

Comment: i'm using XML view, and see my original post for code.

Comment: Note to self: This is a good reason for 'persuading' people to provide full details in the question before answering and downvoting those questions that don't have detail :-)

But I'll leave this response in for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

Have you used the Table inside a (declarative) View? Then the ID will be prefixed to guarantee uniqueness.
Instead of relying on the ID you might want to use `oTable.addStyleClass("mySalesTable");` to assign a CSS class to this table instance. Then you can be sure that exactly this class will be in the HTML and use it for the styling:

`.mySalesTable tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
    background: rgb(245, 245, 245);
}`

If this does not work, check in the developer tools of the browser 1. whether this rule is actually applied and 2. whether it is written by another rule.

Answer (score 0):

Alternate row colors are supported since 1.52 by [`sap.m.Table`](https://openui5nightly.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.Table/methods/setAlternateRowColors) as well as by [`sap.ui.table.Table`](https://openui5nightly.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.table.Table/methods/setAlternateRowColors). Simply set `alternateRowColors="true"`.

### sap.m.Table

[image: UI5 sap.m.Table with alternate row colors]
Sample: https://ui5.sap.com/#/entity/sap.m.Table/sample/sap.m.sample.TableAlternateRowColors

### sap.ui.table.Table

[image: UI5 sap.ui.table.Table with alternate row colors]
Sample: https://ui5.sap.com/#/entity/sap.ui.table.Table/sample/sap.ui.table.sample.RowHighlights
<sup>(Click on <kbd>Toggle Alternate Row Colors</kbd>)</sup>

Answer (score -1):

==================xml===================================

```
<t:Table >
            <t:columns>
                 <t:Column width="11rem">
                    <Label text="标志" />
                    <t:template>
                        <Text text="{
                      path: 'status',
                      formatter: 'yaoji.utils.formatter.format'
                            }" 
                    />
                    </t:template>
                </t:Column>
            </t:columns>
        </t:Table>
```

===================format js===========================

```
yaoji.utils.formatter.format = function (cellValue) {
     this.onAfterRendering= function() {
     //!!! if not after redering, can't get the dom
        var cellId = this.getId(); 
        $("#"+cellId).parent().parent().parent().css("background-                         color","red"); 
     return cellValue;
};
```